# Domains of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following inital value problem:

$$
\frac{\operatorname d y}{\operatorname d t} = \frac 1 {(y + 2)^2},\; y(0) = 1
$$

where $y$ is a real-valued function of $t$. It can easily be solved by separation of variables to obtain

$$
y(t) = (3 t + 27)^{1/3} - 2
$$

Now, I understand that $t = -9$ is outside of the domain of the differential equation, because $y(-9) = -2$, and the first derivative is not defined at $-2$. However, the answer sheet stated that the solution exists only for $t > -9$. My question is: why doesn't it exist for $t < -9$, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We consider a solution to a differential equation to stop existing when it hits a point where the differential equation is undefined: in this case, where the right side $1/(y+2)^2$ has a zero in the denominator.  It may be that the solution has a formula that is still defined on the other side of such a point, and provides a solution of the differential equation there, but we don't consider these as parts of the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

$y(t) = (3 t + 27)^{1/3} - 2$ is defined and continuous for all real $t$, but is not differentiable at $t=-9$. The differential equation is not satisfied at $t=-9$. $y(t)$ is a solution on $(-\infty,-9)$ and on $(-9,\infty)$. Since the initial value is taken at $t=0$, the solution of the initial value problem is considered to be defined on $(-9,\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks! Why do we not take the solution to the initial value problem to be $(-\infty, -9) \cup (-9, +\infty)$, but only $(-9, +\infty)$?

Comment: Because at $t=-9$ the differential equation is not satified.